# Session Persistence in Windows Authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

We use Windows Authentication with a session timeout of 20 seconds.
After 20 seconds, the session expires and the user is redirected to the 
`sessionExpired page`. The problem is this: When the user uses IE,
closes the browser and logs in again using Windows Authentication,
a new session is not created for the same user. The old session remains present, 
and the user is redirected to the `sessionExpired` page again.
What am I missing? What could be the problem?

**Update:**
My Configuration file is as follows

```
<system.web>

    <roleManager enabled="false"/>
    <authentication mode="Windows"  />


    <identity impersonate="true" />     

    <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
      <allow users="*"  />
    </authorization>

    <sessionState timeout="20"/>

    <membership defaultProvider="MyADMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="MyADMembershipProvider"
             type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider, System.Web,     Version=2.0.0.0,  Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
             connectionStringName="ADConnectionString"
             connectionUsername="userName"
             connectionPassword="password"/>
      </providers>
    </membership>
</system.web>
```

Comment: Do you mean 20 minutes? Can you show the configuration for your session please?

Comment: It seems to me that you are mixing session timeout and authentication timeout. They are not the same - as dash suggested if you show the configuration settings we might be able to help you.